# Output loop position number

Tags: entry, loop

Good Evening,

This is probably something really simple, but I need to output the position of the entries in a query within the loop

```
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries().section('memories').limit(10).orderby('RAND()') %}
            
{% for asset in relatedEntries %}
    <div id="locate" class="locate">  
        <div class="portname"><a href="/memory/index.php/bio/{entry_id}"> **LOOP NUMBER HERE**  {{ asset.title }}</a></div>
    </div> 
{% endfor %}
```

I want it to add the number between 1 and 10 depending on its position

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use Twig's loop variable ([docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)).

```
{% for asset in relatedEntries %}
<div id="locate" class="locate">  
  <div class="portname">
    <a href="/memory/index.php/bio/{entry_id}">{{ loop.index }}  {{ asset.title }}</a>
  </div>
</div> 
{% endfor %}
```